# ebay style watch this item

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, e-commerce

Are there any tutorials out there for adding a "watch this" feature to an online store, so users can see when an item is put on sale for example.

My current setup is in php and mysql and I do not offer this feature but would like to give me customers more control over what they are watching and have the ability to be notified when items are put on sale.

All of the products in the shop are listed in a table with unique prod ids. I was then planning on adding a new table for 'sales' - upon a certain event I would like to automate emails to each user who has added the prod id to their watch-list.

Very similar functionality to ebay's watch item feature -but given the potential scale of the work I want to gauge how easy it will be to implement and maintain before committing to much time/effort to it!

Thanks
JD

Comment: You're not really giving a clear definition of what this "watch this" feature would do exactly. What would I be watching if it's about new items - a category? A price group?

Comment: If you think about & describe the individual pieces that go into the "Watch This"-type feature that you want to implement, it will help you  narrow your question to those elements you don't understand.  Are users logging into a system and storing their "watches"? What is the notification scheme? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what you choose to "watch" the general concept is pretty simple. You have a relational table with the user id and the item id. This table is added to on event (click or form submit, however you choose to do so) Either way it is very easy to implement. If you know how to insert to the database then I need not explain the process.

Then you can either run a search and notify script when a table is modified, or run a cron that checks every minute.

This is so vague it hurts my soul to post it, but ultimately the general concept is simple. log a relation. check every minute to see if the user needs to be notified. end of story.

Now, for a more detailed description or actual code, you may want to narrow down your request. It would help to know if you're using a framework or running straight mysql queries. Can you setup a cron? etc.

I'll update if you provide info sufficient for a clear response.

Comment: thanks - appreciate how vague my request was - and can setup cron jobs and insert into sql through php so will put a test version together and come back here should I get stuck. JD